# Alignment of various divs

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, alignment

I am trying to design [this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8pCX.jpg) - refer to the 2nd picture for the overall layout.

- A is 20px high and has to occupy the entire width of the screen.
- B is 100px high and has to occupy the entire width of the screen too.
- C is 200px wide and has to occupy the entire height of the screen, excluding the 120px above it due to A+B.
- D has no restrictions and adapts to the window resizing.

To elaborate on the problem I'm facing currently, look at the 1st picture.

- How do I ensure that the center of B3 is always aligned with the center of the text in div A? B1-B4 are 4 different elements I have in the B div. B1, B2, and B4 should remain in the same place. The only "fluid" part is the change in right/left margins for B3 such that it remains center aligned.

My current code can be found at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qe3oh39o/).

index.html:

```
<div id="A">A</div>
<header>
  <!-- Header is B in the diagram -->
  <div id="B1">B1</div>
  <div id="B2">B2</div>
  <div id="B3">B3</div>
  <div id="B4">B4</div>
</header>
<div id="C">C</div>
<div id="D">D</div>
```

style.css:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#A{
    width:         100vw;
    height:        20px;
    background:    black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #494949;
    color: white;
}

#B1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 47px;
    float: left;
}

#B2 {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 60px;
}

#B3 {
    float: left;
    height: 75px;
    width: 580px;
    margin-top: 12.5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#B4 {
  float: right;
}

#C {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}

#D {
    background-color: #000000;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
}
```

I have a video of what I mean in the comments. Also, I would like to point out that I'm not actually naming the divs by alphabet, did it just for this example.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Here's a video of what I mean](http://sendvid.com/6lmzvwhv).

Comment: I'll try to have a look at this. B1 and B2 will always have fixed width ? Does width( B1 + B2 ) = width( C ) ?

Comment: @Eria - Yes, B1 and B2 will always have a fixed width. And no, the width of C, B1 and B2 are independent. B3 can or can not have a fixed width. My goal is basically for the center of B3 to be aligned to the center of A at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want B3 to be aligned to the center of A, you can't use `float: left` on B1 and B2, because it moves the center of B3 on the right. The only way I found for now is to use absolue positioning on B1, B2 and B4 :

```
header {
    height: 100px;
    background: #494949;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

#B1, #B2, #B4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#B1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 5px;
}

#B2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 150px;
}

#B3 {
  text-align: center;
}

#B4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

[See demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWyEep) (with additionnal color to visualize).

But be careful, iy your text on B3 is to large, it will go under B1, B2 or B4. To avoid this, you can add padding on left and right of B3. But it must be the same value on both side, or the center of B3 won't be aligned to the center of A anymore.

I keep searching for a solution without absolute positioning (beacause I don't like it)...

Comment: Thanks a lot! For all ends and purposes, this does achieve what I set out to do. I will carry on from here and do more research to see if I can streamline it further. Will be sure to update you if I achieve anything new. Really appreciate the help.